# Permitir o zoom em celulares apenas em uma div

Tags: css, html5

Tenho um HTML com a meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes"/>
```

Ou seja, não da para dar zoom em celular.

Mas dentro desse HTML tem uma div que carrega uma imagem. Teria como permitir que apenas essa imagem dentro da div pudesse ser dado o zoom (usando os dois dedos), não influenciando o resto do site?

Comment: De uma olhada [neste artigo](http://dbushell.com/2013/09/10/css-fixed-positioning-and-mobile-zoom/).